# Replace the decimal dot with a comma on an axis in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, localization, decimal-point

This is about the ticks on axes in D3: Is there a way to replace the decimal dot with a comma in numbers? I want the numbers to be displayed like this (which is normal in Germany, such a big number is just for demonstration)

```
1.000.000,1 // This is one million and a tenth
```

and not like this:

```
1,000,000.1
```

I've read the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#d3_format) about the topic, but it seems like there is no possibility!? That's my relevant code so far:

```
localeFormatter = d3.locale({
                "decimal": ".",
                "thousands": ",",
                "grouping": [3],
                "currency": ["", "€"],
                "dateTime": "%a, %e %b %Y, %X",
                "date": "%d.%m.%Y",
                "time": "%H:%M:%S",
                "periods": ["", ""],
                "days": ["Sonntag", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag"],
                "shortDays": ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"],
                "months": ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
                "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"]
            });


numberFormat = localeFormatter.numberFormat("04.,"); // The setting is applied, but has not the desired effect...

yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left")
                .tickFormat(numberFormat);
```

Comment: Have you had a look at this https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat specifically *axis.tickFormat(d3.format(",.0f")) will display integers with comma-grouping for thousands*

Comment: That was the point that brought me to the page I linked in my question... But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the following settings for `d3.locale`:

```
var localeFormatter = d3.locale({
      "decimal": ",",
      "thousands": ".",
      ...
    });
```

Note that I have changed the `.` in `,` and vice versa. And with:

```
var numberFormat = localeFormatter.numberFormat(",.2f");
```

I print the number using a thousands separator `,` (it uses a `.` as defined in the locale) and two digits after the comma `.2f`:

```
console.log(numberFormat(1000000.1)); // "1.000.000,10"
```